Step in derivation of the short distance behavior of the heat kernel in Francesco's Conformal field theory book equation 5.190
Can someone explain equation 5.190 of Francesco's Conformal Field Theory? It is a step in the derivation of the short distance behavior of the heat kernel in Francesco's Conformal field theory book.
It says: to first order
$$G(x,y;t) =\left<x,t|A^{-1}|y,0\right> + \int d\tau dz\ \left<x,t|A^{-1}|z,\tau\right>\left<z,\tau|B A^{-1}|y,0\right>$$
$$=G_0(x,y;t)+\int_0^t d\tau\int d^2z\ G_0(x,z;t-\tau) $$
$$\times \left\{a^{\mu\nu}(z)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^\mu \partial z^\nu} + b^\mu(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z^\mu} \right\}G_0(z,y;\tau).$$
Where $A = \partial_t - \partial_\mu \partial^\mu$, $B = a^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu  + b^\mu \partial_\mu$,
$$G(x,y;t) =\left<x,t\left|\frac{1}{A-B}\right|y,0\right>$$
and
$$\frac{1}{A-B} = \frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{A}B\frac{1}{A} + \ldots$$
In particular the term
$$\left\{a^{\mu\nu}(z)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^\mu \partial z^\nu} + b^\mu(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z^\mu} \right\}G_0(z,y;\tau)$$
is unclear to me: We see that it comes from $B$, but why is it with respect to the $z$ variable and not $y$?
Also why do we go from $dz$ to $d^2z$?
